# Запретить выход PictureBox за границы Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

Я пишу программу, где изображение (PictureBox) не должно выходит за границы Panel. Все сделал, но все равно что-то не так... За левую и правую границы картинка не выходит, а вот за верхнюю и нижнюю очень даже, и потом "не отпускает". Вот код:

```
    void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        int currentKey = e.KeyValue;
        switch (currentKey)
        {
            case 37:
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - 2, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
                if (pictureBox1.Left <= 0)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 2, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
                }
                break;
            case 38:
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y - 2);
                if (pictureBox1.Bottom >= panel1.ClientSize.Height)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y + 2);
                }
                break;
            case 39:
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X + 2, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
                if (pictureBox1.Right >= panel1.ClientSize.Width)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - 2, pictureBox1.Location.Y);
                }
                break;
            case 40:
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y + 2);
                if (pictureBox1.Top <= 0)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y - 2);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: а зачем вы присваиваете новую позицию сразу? сохраните в переменную класса `Point`, проверьте, потом присваивайте. А так получается что вы сначала двигаете картинку без проверки, потом проверяете и откатываете если обнаружили что двигать было нельзя.

Comment: Поподробнее, пожалуйста...

Comment: ок, а еще у вас похоже верх и низ перепутан. подпишите в комментариях к коду куда какая клавиша двигает что ли, раз уж стандартные константы не используете.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

у вас сейчас так:

```
case 40:
    //тут вы сдвигаете картинку
    pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y + 2);
    //проверяете что сдвинули правильно
    if (pictureBox1.Top <= 0)
    {
        //возвращаете если сдвинули неправильно
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y - 2);
    }
    break;
```

а нужно так:

```
case 40://допустим это вниз
    //вычисляем новое положение
    Point newPosition = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y + 2);
    //проверяем новое значение
    if (newPosition.Y <= panel1.ClientSize.Height - pictureBox1.Height)
    {
        //сдвигаем картинку если все правильно
        pictureBox1.Location = newPosition;
    }
    break;
```

аналогично для каждого случая

Comment: Спасибки! Очень рад!